# REGEXEXTRACT and French accents in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, regex, regexextract

I have the following formula:

```
 =REGEXEXTRACT(source!A2,"^[\w\s\À-ÿ]+")
```

where

```
 source!A2="Ancien Marché Saint-Jacques (1125, rue Ontario Est)"
```

and I would like to extract

```
Ancien Marché Saint-Jacques
```

however I'm getting an error saying

```
Invalid escape sequence: \À
```

Any other idea on how to deal with the French characters?

Comment: Well, I got it to work changing my expression to:

     ^[\w\s\\À-ÿ-’']+

so double escaping seems to be required in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got it to work changing my expression to:

```
^[\w\s\\À-ÿ-’']+
```

so double escaping seems to be required in this case

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets, used in your regex example, indicate that you are searching for text within brackets. Losing the first straight bracket, wouldn't yield the expected outcome.

Therefore, if this is the way all data is being presented,

`Description of Object (postal code, street)`,

then this will be of use as well:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(source, "("),1,1)
```

The `SPLIT()` function will split the result, where the first `(` occurs. The `INDEX()` function will only show the first row (1) on the first column (1).

Comment: Hi @Jacob, great suggestion (i guess once one learn how to use a hammer (regex) everything looks like nails). Unfortunately, for me, while all the information is withing brackets, not all of them is the expected address. Example:

`Cathédrale Saint-Jacques-le-Majeur (aujourd'hui cathédrale Maie-Reine-du-Monde - boulevard Dorchester Ouest, aujourd'hui boulevard René-Lévesque Ouest)` 
(here I don't expect anything in return, it is just too complex)

`Bibliothèque Saint-Sulpice (devenue Bibliothèque nationale du Québec- 1700, rue Saint-Denis)`
Here I'm getting 1700, rue Saint-Denis, which is ok

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to Find (`(.+)\s\(.+`)/Replace(`$1`) on a copy:

[image: WA47188 example]

<sub>Always best to avoid dealings with French characters.</sub>